# Check if is equal results in array php

Tags: php, arrays

i have a problem, i got an array what is generated dinamically and has a random values, the array length could be variable, is not always the same, my issue is that i have to check the array values and see if there is same values, for instances:

```
$arr = [1,1,1,4]; //check how many values are the same [PHP CODE]
```

i tryied before with in_array() but i dont have clearly a good way to do that.

```
if (in_array($result, $arr)) {
   echo "in array";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_count_values`

is what you're looking for!

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>

//prints
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [hello] => 2
    [world] => 1
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print_r(array_count_values($arr))` to see the number of times that each number appears in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
        $arr_count = array_count_values($array);

        $count = 0;
        $val_arr = array();
        foreach($arr_count as $key => $val)
        {
            if($val > 1)
            {
                $count++;
                $val_arr[] = $key;
            }
        }

        if($count == 0)
        {
            echo 'Array has no common values.';
        }
        else {
            echo 'Array has '.$count.' common values:';

            foreach($val_arr as $val)
            {
                echo "<b>".$val."</b> ";
            }
        }        
        ?>
```

Use your array in place of $array variable.